Unable to update the currentIndex to the one where the selected modal is opened
I have a class where I can open the gallery. The problem is that this line of code doesn't reflect to the currentIndex. As a result, whenever you click a gallery img, it opens the gallery and its Index always starts at 0. It shows up whenever you click next or previous. I'll post the whole code in the snippet. I appreciate all the help.
class ModalManager {
  #modals;
  #currentIndex;
  #myModalDialog;

  constructor(
    modalSelector,
    catalogSelector
  ) {
    this.#modals = document.querySelectorAll(modalSelector);
    this.#currentIndex = 0;
    this.#myModalDialog = document.querySelector("#modal-dial");
    this.#bindCatalogClick(catalogSelector);
    this.#bindModalClick();
  }

  #openModal(index, direction) {
    this.#modals.forEach((modal, i) => {
      modal.style.display = i === index ? "block" : "none";
      modal.classList.remove("animate-left", "animate-right");
      if (i === index) {
        const animationClass =
          direction === "left" ? "animate-left" : "animate-right";
        modal.classList.add(animationClass);
      }
    });
    this.#currentIndex = index;
    console.log(index);
  }


  #bindCatalogClick(catalogSelector) {
    document
      .querySelector(catalogSelector)
      .addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
        if (!target.matches("img[data-modal]")) return;
        this.#myModalDialog.className = target.dataset.modal;
        this.#myModalDialog.classList.add("modal-fade-in");
        console.log(this.#currentIndex);
        setTimeout(
          () => this.#myModalDialog.classList.remove("modal-fade-in"),
          500
        );
        this.#myModalDialog.showModal();
      });
  }
}

const modalManager = new ModalManager(
  ".gallery",
  "#next-img",
  "#prev-img",
  ".catalog__wrapper"
);


edit:
Guys! I managed to fix it! The problem was because the #openModal was never called in the first place, after reading my notes from my studying sessions, I used parseInt to find the corresponding index.
I'm just keeping this post so I could look back at my journey in the future. Thank you for taking the time to read this post.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yes, it looks like that's what the `#openModal' method would do, if it was ever called. I've just tried debugging your site in the browser's dev tools, and it seems that this method is never called. So maybe take a good look at the code where you think it should be called from (and edit it into your question). Also, there's quite a lot of code in the question which isn't really related to the question, e.g. for moving images around within a modal once it's open - consider removing that code until what remains is the minimum needed to reproduce ...

... the problem you want to solve, i.e. keeping track of which modal has been opened when the user clicks on an image in the main page. Stack Overflow folks call this a minimal, reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@sbridewell Hello, thank you very much. It was my bad from the start that it actually doesn't use the #openModal to open the modal... I've been so confused for the past few hours...
then I remembered, I added the #openModal to accomodate the previous and next image... I'll take a look at this further.
Also, I'm still new to stack overflow since I started my coding journey a few months ago, I'll try to study the MRE so I don't bother the other members too much

If you've found a solution, please consider posting an Answer to your Question, showing how you fixed the problem. That way, others looking for a solution to a similar problem will see that your Question has been Answered, and are more likely to see it. It's absolutely fine (and encouraged) to post answers to your own questions (I've done it a few times), see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

The problem was pointed out by @sbridwell. From the start, I never called #openModal, so, although #openModal has the ability to set the #currentIndex to whatever the Index of #openModal is, it was never called.
The solution is call #openModal into the code that opens the modals, which in my case is bindCatalogClick. But, if I just called it out it would always return NaN which is fair enough since #openModal method wouldn't be translated properly. The solution I found was from another post using parseInt and adding 'data-index' in the corresponding Index. Since #openModal uses two parameters, I just put in a default direction to serve as a placeholder. Surprisingly, it worked well and had an animation bonus that came with it from another method. Here is the code which I added to the bindCatalogSelector:
const index = parseInt(target.dataset.index, 10); // Assuming each img has a data-index attribute
const direction = "left"; // Default direction, could be dynamic based on some logic
this.#openModal(index, direction);

